# Calculus Continuous & Differentiable

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+c& \text{if } x \leq c,\\
1 &\text{if x > c}
\end{cases}$

(a) Find a value for c so that the function f is continuous.

(b) Is the function f differentiable at c? Explain.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  What is your question about the excercise you wrote above? What have you tryed and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Maybe you should begin by drawing graphs for different values of $c$ to have an idea of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f$ to be continuous we want $f(c) = 1$.  So we want $2c = 1$ so $c=1/2$.

For $f$ to be differentiable at $c$ we need the left and right derivatives to be the same.  Coming from the left $f' = 0$ and coming from the right $f' = 1$ therefore it's not possible for $f$ to be differentiable at $c$.